# 4-point Likert scale

Tags: model, terminology, likert

I have compiled a questionnaire using a glossary of terms. I have 4 options that people can select. The terms are; I don't understand the word and I can't define it / I understand it but I never use it / I understand it and I use it with family and friends / I understand it and use it with doctors and other professionals.

Even though the scale is not " extremely good / good / neutral / a little bad / worse" (for example) as I have seen on other questionnaires using name 'likert scale', can I still use this term to label my questionnaire? 
If not, is there a more applicable model for me to look at?

Comment: One goal in creating a set of options is that they are mutually exclusive. This means that no respondent could look at them and not find an option that fits. Your options are not mutually exclusive. Moreover, they are double-barreled, mixing comprehension with occasion. Finally, describing it as a "4-point Likert scale" is a misnomer. By definition, Likert scales are 5-point, ordinal, agree-disagree questions. Your response set is nominal, not ordinal. If you want to use Likerts, break it into a 5-point, agree-disagree item for comprehension and a second multiple choice item for occasion

Comment: Quite honestly and with all due respect, it's apparent that your questionnaire design skills aren't that technically strong. Are you a student? If so, then this is excusable. If not and this is a corporate project, why not consider delegating this to someone who knows what they're doing?

Comment: @MikeHunter: "Mutually exclusive" means no respondent could look at them and find more than one option that fits; "jointly exhaustive" means no respondent could look at them and not find an option that fits. Both would be seem to be desirable properties for a questionnaire item.

Comment: @MikeHunter yes, you have guessed..I am a doing a Masters course , and really questionnaires are a newly touched on area.  Thanks for your input though, and, understanding.

Comment: Though an authoritative answer would be welcome, both our [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/likert) & the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likert_scale) suggest that the definitions implied by actual usage range from very narrow to very broad. [Uebersax (2006), "Likert scales: dispelling the confusion", *Statistical Methods for Rater Agreement* website](http://www.john-uebersax.com/stat/likert.htm) has given the issue some thought, & following his advice would perhaps lead to "ordered-category item" for each individual question - if indeed you wish ...

Comment: ... to treat the responses as ordered. Note that his characteristics #4 & #5 depend on what the item's supposed to be measuring - editing your question to provide this information might be helpful.

Comment: @Dandelion  No problem. I have one followup to the commentary. It may help to think in terms of the broader framework within which the general question of scaling and scale types rests. To the best of my knowledge, a mathematical psychologist named Clyde Coombs developed a MECE (mutually exclusive, completely exhaustive) classification of scales that remains actionable. Coombs classified scales into 4 buckets: nominal, ordinal, interval and ratio scales. I'm running out of space, so here's a link to a reasonable discussion: http://www.socialresearchmethods.net/kb/measlevl.php  Hope this helps

Comment: @Mike Hunter Nominal, ordinal, interval and ratio scales were distinguished by Samuel S. Stevens working before Coombs.  Stevens, S. S. 1946. On the theory of scales of measurement. _Science_ 103: 677–680 is an early reference, but Stevens revisited these questions many times.

Comment: @NickCox  Right you are! Apologies for conflating two great scholars.