# Does a Likert Scale have to be 5-point?

Tags: likert

In one comment to a question on Likert Scales, it was stated by a contributor that "By definition, Likert scales are 5-point, ordinal, agree-disagree questions" ([4-point Likert scale](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155790/4-point-likert-scale)).

I have read a considerable amount of literature on Likert Scales and I have not come across this 'definition' previously. I am aware Likert Scales are ordinal and work best in the agree-disagree space (although that will depend on the actual context of the Likert question/statement being answered). However, in literature there are many articles and research that refer to Likert Scales using an array of different constructions. For example, there is plenty of literature which backs a 7-point Likert Scale and the debate around the appropriateness of the 'neutral' point continues.

My question: Is there such a strict definition that a Likert Scale must have to be 5-point and, if so, why? If this is the case, it would be good if a peer reviewed reference can be provided to explain why.

Comment: look it up on Wikipedia and follow the references if you need to know more

Comment: @ Robert Jones. That is no help (and is dismissive of my question). I have read well over 100 articles on Likert Scales and analysis so I am no novice at this.  I am well acquainted with qualitative and quantitative methods as it is critical to my profession.  As stated,  I am asking a specific question about a supposed definition of Likert Scales that seems at odds with a significant amount of practice. Pointing generically to Wikipedia is lazy and suggests to me that the "definition" a Likert Scale must be 5-point is more driven by convention than based on some sound measurement theory.